# Resource usage from Ambari

Tags: hadoop, hive, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I have few Hive jobs and Mapreduce programs running in my cluster. I am able to check in Ambari about general resource utilization. But I want to see the resources utilized by individual applications. Is it possible through Ambari API? Can you provide some clues?

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge metrics that are provided by Ambari are for whole cluster.
But you can check MapReduce2 Job History UI, it seems like you are looking for this stuff. Check this link out, there is more detailed description there

http://hortonworks.com/blog/elephants-can-remember-mapreduce-job-history-in-hdp-2-0/

Comment: I do see this particular UI provided by Mapreduce 2. I could see the counter information only for Mapreduce jobs not for Hive queries. Is there any way I can find out the resource usage for Hive queries as well?